# How to run multiple chrome profiles in different remote debuging ports in ubuntu?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, remote-debugging

I have 2 chrome profiles. My aim is to control these 2 windows using puppeteer. So first, I have to open these profile windows via command line, specifying the debugging ports.

command 1: `google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9222 --profile-directory="Default"`

command 2: `google-chrome --remote-debugging-port=9223 --profile-directory="Profile 1"`

When 1st command is executed, it opens a chrome window with the profile I mentioned. And I also get a WS URL for that browser. So I can use that in puppeteer.
Problem is while running second command. It also opens the profile, but no URL. It says "Opening in existing browser session".
I want to open more profiles and control them with puppeteer. Please help.